# Flask - G variable not accessible in multi threaded context

Tags: python, flask

I am using ThreadPoolExecutor to create threads in my application. When I try to access the Flask g variable in any of the thread pool tasks, it gives me error

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
```

I tried using app.app_context() as well but it fails with error

```
AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'Test'
```

Is there anyway I can access the g variable in multi-threaded context?

Sample code to reproduce the issue.

```
from flask import Flask, g
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=False)


@app.before_request
def before_req():
    g.Test = 'test'

@app.route("/test", methods=["GET"])
def handle_request():

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        response = executor.submit(t1)
        var = response.result()
        print(var)


def t1():
    # with app.app_context():
   return g.Test
```

Comment: `g` is a thread local, meaning it is bound to the current thread.

Comment: As per the answer on this question, we can pass app context to thread. Is there any similar concept available for thread executor? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476889/use-flask-current-app-logger-inside-threading